# remove special character in structure variable

Tags: c

`what_if_var[0].price` (type is `char [10]`) has the value of "$15555.665". Is there is anyway to remove "$" from the value (like "15555.665") and convert the value into double?

Comment: If price is char[10], then the value '$15555.665' is a buffer overrun.  Careful.

Comment: @Paul Good catch. @jcrshankar The nul terminator requires an 11th byte.

Comment: great paul.. i just gave it as example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you always know that the `'$'` is going to be the first character, you could just try:

```
double num = strtod (what_if_var[0].price + 1, NULL);
```

Comment: You could also call `atof()`, though some in polite society consider that deprecated.

Comment: thanks chris... is there is anyway to convert string to double.

Comment: @jcrshankar `strtod()` stands for "*string* to *double*". This is exactly the function you're looking for.

Comment: sorry..chris.. i need to copy the value as string into same structure variable after some calculation.. so i need convertion of double to string.

Comment: @jcrshankar I don't understand what you're asking for. Converting a double to a string is generally through `sprintf()`; copying a string is simply `strcpy()` if the space is already allocated.

Comment: sprintf(what_if_var[0].price ,num) , i need to copy the the value of double to strcture variable. how to do tat chris?

Answer (score 1):

Check the function [strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/), converts a string to double.